# Every (sync) functions from a specific files are blocking tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm trying to test my new component and I don't know why every functions from a specific file are blocking my tests and I don't understand why because they all are synchrone functions.
My tests are passing because of the timeout but the code always stop at these functions.

I'm using 2 functions atLeastOneCheckbox() (custom Validator) and getRealCheckedValues() (which return formcontrol real values for checkbox control)

I'm importing them like that:

```
import { atLeastOneCheckbox, getRealCheckedValues } from '@core/validators/validators.service';
```

And here are the content of the file:

```
import { ValidatorFn, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

/**
 * Validators that require at least x checkbox checked
 * @param minRequired Number of checkbox required
 */
export function atLeastOneCheckbox(minRequired = 1): ValidatorFn {
  return function validate(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    let checked = 0;

    if (!formGroup.controls) {
      return null;
    }

    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach((key) => {
      const control = formGroup.controls[key];

      if (control.value) {
        checked++;
      }
    });

    if (checked < minRequired) {
      return {
        requireCheckboxToBeChecked: true,
      };
    }

    return null;
  };
}

/**
 * Return the real values of checked checkbox
 * @param aChecked FormArray values
 * @param aValues  Checkbox values
 */
export function getRealCheckedValues(aChecked: boolean[], aValues: any[]): any[] {
  return aValues.filter((val: any, index: number) => aChecked[index]);
}

// custom validator to check that two fields match
export function MustMatch(controlName: string, matchingControlName: string) {
  return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
    const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];
    const matchingControl = formGroup.controls[matchingControlName];

    if (matchingControl.errors && !matchingControl.errors.mustMatch) {
      // return if another validator has already found an error on the matchingControl
      return;
    }

    // set error on matchingControl if validation fails
    if (control.value !== matchingControl.value) {
      matchingControl.setErrors({ mustMatch: true });
    } else {
      matchingControl.setErrors(null);
    }
  };
}
```

And my test block here:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      // Response grids section
      grids: this.formBuilder.group({
        respGrid: this.formBuilder.array(grids), atLeastOneCheckbox(1))
      }),
    })
```

And here (every value used inside the function are corrects):

```
const selectTransportationType = getRealCheckedValues(
      this.f.informations.controls.transportationType.value,
      this.aSubcontracts.map((sub: SubcontractData) => sub.key)
    );
```

Even if I try to console.log right inside the function, the log is never called and I don't understand why.

If someone can enlighten me please

Comment: `respGrid: this.formBuilder.array(grids), atLeastOneCheckbox(1))` this line doesn't seem like correct JS syntax to me.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev how would you write it ? I don't see what's wrong with this line

Comment: When I paste it in my code editor there are syntax errors. I would fix them first before doing anything.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev thanks for your help but there is no syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the problem.
Every functions from this file was undefined because the path use an alias that doesn't work when testing '@core' and I don't know why.
But replace '@core' by '@app/core' correct the issue in my case.